# Async task is stuck in a deadlock

Tags: xamarin, async-await

I am trying to do an async task in xamarin studio ( c#) but i'm missing something about async/await. Here is my code. It never finishes this function.

```
public static async Task<string> AsyncTask()
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "thing1", "this is the second time" },
                { "thing2", "world" }
            };

                var content =  new  FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

                var response = await client.PostAsync(DATA_SOURCE, content);

                var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("PART 2:" + responseString);
                _json = responseString;
                return _json;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Show the code calling the above function. Somewhere higher up the stack there is a blocking call like "`.Result` or `.Wait`" check if they exist.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you may be calling this from a WPF or WinForms context. If I'm correct the following applies and is a common source of confusion:

When you await an async method call, by default it will continue on the captured context (the UI context if this is being called from UI code). In that case, the UI context is busy and is also captured and so a deadlock will occur.

What you should do is add .ConfigureAwait(false) to each awaited method call.

```
async MethodCall(...).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

This will allow a different context to resume execution of the method after the async call completes, and thus will avoid the deadlock. Note: this is especially important for all library code to work in this manner so that it is safe to call from a UI context.

Many people wish this was the default behavior and that you would instead opt-in to force it to resume on the same context, but maintaining backward compatibility precluded that decision.